# GSAP TimeLineLite.to() passing variables to the third parameter does not work.

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, gsap

I am trying to use variables for all four of the parameters in `TimeLineLite.to(param1, param2, param3, param4);`

parameters 1, 2, and 4 take variables just fine, however, parameter 3 explodes when I put any type of variable into it. I need some help understanding why!

The parameters are structured as so `.to( target:Object, duration:Number, {vars:Object}, position:* );`

This is the documentation I've looked at so far, however, I cannot find anything about passing variables to the parameters, or any indication as to why it shouldn't work.

1) [TimeLineLite intro section](http://greensock.com/sequence-video)

2) [.to() documentaion](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/to/)

Also, here is a codepen with the two models, they are both identical besides for parameter 3. You can click anywhere to restart the animation. Can someone please help me figure out why the second GreenSock guy will not move?

codepen: [codepen.io example of my problem.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGVwKL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to reference to an object key with a variable, you would need to wrap them in square brackets.

Consider the following example:

```
var direction = 'left';
var someObject = { left: 200 };
console.log(someObject.direction);
console.log(someObject[direction]);
```

The first `console.log` statement would return `undefined` because no such `key` by the name of `direction` is present inside `someObject`. However, the second `console.log` call would return the value of `200` because you treated `direction` as a variable which stores another string value stored in it i.e. `'left'` and after computation this would turn into `someObject['left']` which, hence, returns you the correct result of `200`.

In a nutshell, change your `variableDriver.to(...)` line to:

`variableDriven.to(".variable-driven", 3, { [direction]: distance });`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Tahir Ahmed. You really helped me tonight, and taught me something!! I'll make sure to return the favor :D

Comment: reply to any questions by anyone you think you know the answers to, you will then have returned the favour :)